# Swagger api client methods return void

Tags: java, api, testing, swagger, codegen

Swagger api client, generated by codegen tool, only creates tests methods with return type **void**. How can I test my rest api ?

This is my service code specification:

```
 @Api(value = "Authentication Recovery")
 @Path("/authenticationRecovery")

public class AuthenticationRecoveryResource implements Authentication{

@ApiOperation(
        value = "Recover access token"
        , notes = "Recover access token assigned to the user (once it has been authenticated)"
        , response = TokenJAXB.class
        //, responseContainer = "List"
)
@ApiResponses(value = { 
        @ApiResponse(code = HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK, message = "Authorized access") ,
        @ApiResponse(code = HttpURLConnection.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED, message = "Unauthorized access") 
})
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public Response authenticate(
        @ApiParam(value="Username", required=true) @FormParam("username") String username,
        @ApiParam(value="Password", required=true) @FormParam("password") String password) 
{..}
```

And this is my generated swagger code for testing:

```
/**
  * API tests for AuthenticationRecoveryApi
*/
@Ignore

public class AuthenticationRecoveryApiTest {

private final AuthenticationRecoveryApi api = new AuthenticationRecoveryApi();

/**
 * Recover access token
 *
 * Recover access token assigned to the user (once it has been authenticated)
 *
 * @throws ApiException
 *             if the Api call fails
 */
@Test
public void authenticateTest() throws ApiException {
    String username = null;
    String password = null;
    api.authenticate(username, password);

    // TODO: test validations
}}
```

I have generate a swagger client api with:

```
java -jar swagger-codegen-2.2.3/modules/swagger-codegen-cli/target/swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate -i http://localhost:8080/myproject/services/service0/swagger.json -l java -o client/myproject/java
```

Comment: Can you post your spec? Which language/framework did you generate?

Answer (score 2):

The `Java` Generator for `Swagger Codegen` does the best that it can - it has test code with functions (more like function stubs) where you can fill in the value of the parameters to be passed to the API endpoints, such as the variables `String username` and `String password` above. After that, the api endpoint is called.

After the api call (`api.authenticate(username, password)` above), you must somehow validate whether the response was successful. This needs a human element depending on your API, and the `// TODO` comment is a hint for you to do the same.

If the API is called successfully, you do nothing and the void function exits. Else, your code needs to throw a `ApiException` as written in the comments.